# oh-my-zsh cursor up before program has finished vs after, how to make them behave consistently

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I've noticed that if I press up arrow at a prompt then I get the previous command and up again gets me the command before that.

Whereas if I press up arrow **before the previous program has completed** then instead I get the previous command displayed, the cursor is at the end of the line, but oh-my-zsh is now in "search for lines that start with ... " mode meaning I can't press up to get the previous command.

I'm sure this behavior is well known and expected but just in case you don't get it you can repo it like this

1. Type `ls` <kbd>return</kbd>
2. Type `sleep 3` <kbd>return</kbd>
3. wait 3 seconds for prompt to appear
4. press <kbd>⬆</kbd>  (should show `sleep 3`)
5. press <kbd>⬆</kbd>  again (should show `ls`)
6. press <kbd>return</kbd>  (to run `ls`)
7. Type `sleep 3` <kbd>return</kbd>  <kbd>⬆</kbd>  (press the up arrow before the 3 seconds elapses)
8. It should now be showing `sleep 3`
9. Press <kbd>⬆</kbd>
   it will still be showing `sleep 3` but it want it to be showing `ls`. Instead it is in "search for commands that start with `sleep 3` mode instead of just `go to previous command` mode.

To make try to clear in both cases these are the steps

1. ls<kbd>return</kbd>
2. sleep 3<kbd>return</kbd>
3. <kbd>⬆</kbd>
4. <kbd>⬆</kbd>

But they end up with different results depending on if step3 happens before or after step2 finishes.

Note I saw this Q&A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324623/how-to-make-oh-my-zsh-history-behavior-similar-to-bashs

But that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I like oh-my-zsh's partial line + up = search for lines that start with the partial. What I'm trying to fix is that if I press up on step 2 above it magically inserts a partial where as if I wait until step 2 finishes it doesn't.

How do I get oh-my-zsh to be consistent here so that a premature up arrow behaves the same as a normal up arrow?

I'm surprised this question isn't common. It's seriously infuriating to have the terminal act inconsistently. I'd except most devs using oh-my-zsh to run  into this issue all the time and be massively frustrated.

The example above with `sleep 3` is only to make it easy to show the problem. In actual usage the problem happens frequently even with short lived commands. I type say `git status` <kbd>return</kbd> `git commit somefile -m "short comment"` <kbd>return</kbd> <kbd>⬆</kbd><kbd>⬆</kbd> expecting to see "git status". 66% of the time I get `git status` and the other 34% I get `git commit somefile -m "short comment" and pressing <kbd>⬆</kbd> again just blinks the cursor and I have to press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to break out of zsh's partial complete mode.

The fact that this does not seem to be a common complaint for oh-my-zsh makes me wonder if I have something setup wrong.

To make it clearer run `zsh` without oh-my-zsh.

```
zsh -d -f
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search
```

Now try the steps above. You'll get consistent behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an overkill solution but, following [this](https://coderwall.com/p/jpj_6q/zsh-better-history-searching-with-arrow-keys) guide you can see that you can bind new actions to the up/down arrow key. So if you add:

```
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search # Up
bindkey "^[[B" down-line-or-beginning-search # Down
```

to your `~/.zshrc`, it should remove the functionality you talked about. I managed to get it to work while still maintaining regular search capabilities but this is not thoroughly tested and should probably be used with care.

Comment: Yes, I have the same behavior - In my test what happens is that pressing up doesn't do anything until the command completes and than I can press up twice to return to `ls`

Comment: The reason why I think this is a good solution is that when you work regularly, up/down still iterate over the history, and partial searches continue to work.

Comment: I don't know why but it works as I want it to work if I leave off the `-r`. Maybe you could update your answer so I don't have to leave a new one?